# Laravel migrate large data by locking and creating new table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel 10 project using MySQL 8.0. I need to make some schema changes to a few tables with millions of rows. My best approach here is to create a new table with the new schema, set the auto incrementing to be the last ID, and then at a later date copy over the differences, but when I attempt to run my migration here, I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1100 Table 'applications_new' was not locked with LOCK TABLES (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table `applications_new` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, `company_id` bigint unsigned not null, `country_id` bigint unsigned not null, `product_id` bigint unsigned not null, `affiliate_product_id` bigint unsigned not null, `pingtree_group_id` bigint unsigned not null, `selected_pingtree_id` bigint unsigned null, `affiliate_id` bigint unsigned not null, `affiliate_campaign_id` bigint unsigned null, `api_request_log_id` bigint unsigned null, `thread_uuid` char(36) not null, `status` varchar(255) not null, `status_metadata` json null, `additional_info` json null, `modelable_type` varchar(255) null, `modelable_id` bigint unsigned null, `brand` varchar(255) null, `ip` varchar(45) not null, `user_agent` text not null, `fingerprint` varchar(255) not null, `submitted_at` timestamp not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Here's my code, what am I missing:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('applications')) {
            if (! Schema::hasTable('applications_new')) {

                // 1. Create new table in prep
                Schema::create('applications_new', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->id();

                    // define how this model links
                    $table->foreignId('user_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('company_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('country_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('product_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('affiliate_product_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('pingtree_group_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('selected_pingtree_id')->index()->nullable();
                    $table->foreignId('affiliate_id')->index();
                    $table->foreignId('affiliate_campaign_id')->index()->nullable();
                    $table->foreignId('api_request_log_id')->index()->nullable();

                    // create a thread UUID for checking application
                    $table->uuid('thread_uuid')->index();

                    // application status, using PHP enums
                    $table->string('status')->index();
                    $table->json('status_metadata')->nullable();
                    $table->json('additional_info')->nullable();

                    // define the relationship to the polymorphic relationship.
                    // e.g: ApplicationUkPayday or another form of model linking to the application
                    $table->nullableMorphs('modelable');

                    // attribution
                    $table->string('brand')->nullable()->index();

                    // other metadata about this application that could be useful
                    $table->ipAddress('ip');
                    $table->text('user_agent');
                    $table->string('fingerprint');

                    // date/times
                    $table->timestamp('submitted_at')->index();
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }

            if (Schema::hasTable('applications_new')) {

                // 2. Lock applications and get newest lead
                DB::statement('LOCK TABLES applications WRITE');
                $lastAutoIncrement = DB::table('applications')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

                // 3. Lock applications new whilst we change it's auto incrementing ID
                if ($lastAutoIncrement) {
                    DB::statement('LOCK TABLES applications_new WRITE');
                    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE applications_new AUTO_INCREMENT = ' . ($lastAutoIncrement->id + 1));

                    // 4. Lock applications whilst we rename it
                    DB::statement('LOCK TABLES applications WRITE');
                    Schema::rename('applications', 'applications_backup');

                    // 5. Lock application new whilst we switch it to 'applications'
                    DB::statement('LOCK TABLES applications_new WRITE');
                    Schema::rename('applications_new', 'applications');

                    // 6. Unlock everything now
                    DB::statement('UNLOCK TABLES');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        // TODO: can we handle rollback?
    }
};
```

#### UPDATE

I get this error now...

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1100 Table 'migrations' was not locked with LOCK TABLES (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (2023_09_21_090721_migrate_commissions_table, 2))

Comment: _"The following statements are prohibited while a `LOCK TABLES` statement is in effect: `CREATE TABLE`, ..."_ (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#lock-tables-restrictions)

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out, but after this I now get this error: ` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1100 Table 'migrations' was not locked with LOCK TABLES (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (2023_09_21_090721_migrate_commissions_table, 2))`